# issue with print new content on new page with jquery

Tags: jquery, printing

I want to do content print for that I have made below code

```js
 w = window.open(window.location.href,"_blank");
w.document.open();
w.document.write(res);
w.document.close();
w.window.print();
```

everything is working properly but when the table has more content and it is continued on the next page it is showing overlap like [image]

I want it table continued it shows on next page

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: It seems that your print settings are set to have no margin. This is not something that JS has control over - it's set by the local PC

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and what settings we need to do for that can you please help me